# Cocoa First-Run Configuration Wizard

Tags: cocoa, installation, wizard

I have a "drag to install" OS X app. When the app is first launched I want to have a configuration wizard which does things like collect the user's username, password, etc. In total there were will be about 7 steps. The user should be able to move forwards and backwards through the configuration steps.

I'm wondering if there is a pre-existing solution (ala template) to something like this? If not, is there standard method of creating such a wizard in Cocoa?

Thanks in advance!
CS